# Unable to resolve dependency in latest android studio. Why and what is the issue in latest android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

## Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01

[image]

> I know solution but I want know what is the main issue in latest android studio and why??? 
>   just changing the dependencies problem is fix as shown in below: Friends my question is why and what is the issue in latest android studio any another solution for this issue ...please help me out

### Build : Gradle project

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

### Build : Gradle Module

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myXYZ.MyApp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Friends my question is too clear, why this issue in android studio 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

By your version of gradle plugin I assume you are using not the latest Android studio, but 3.1.x.
Try to use 3.2.5 beta from Canary (Beta) channel. It might help